# What is this receptacle that is wired to a pair of phone lines(?) with a hole in the middle?

Tags: receptacle

We live in a new-to-us Southern US late 1970s single family home. We have an outlet in the bedroom which is wired to what I think is a pair of phone lines (?), but the actual “outlet” is just a hole. You could literally pass a wire or something down the middle. What is this?

The only lettering seen is on the metal support bracket which says “SE-43A” and appears to just be the support bracket, not the wired component.

[image: unknown wired plug/outlet]
[image: rear of unknown plug]
[image: side profile]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You hit the nail on the head. It's a vintage phone jack and the phone cord would actually go down the middle of it and the connections made from the back screw terminals. There was a small metal cable stop that was cripped to the end of the cord to prevent the cord from being yanked out. This was usually the way phones were installed way back when. They then started using the bulky 4 prong plugs before finally going to the little plastic clipins we know today.

Comment: For a home built in the 70s the phone wiring must've been put in by an old tech who was anti-modular or even 4-pin jacks.  I'm guessing this was not a Bell/Baby Bell phone system.  This would be appropriate for a home built in the early 50s.

Comment: @TigerGuy Yes, early to mid 50's.  Usually when people only had one phone in the house and maybe a party line. The OP might be a little off on the year of construction.

Comment: I have confirmed with multiple documents that the home was built in 1977.

Comment: @Alec  Guessing that they had an old phone with the wire and wanted to use it so they added the vintage outlet.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bracket for mounting phone jacks that is either missing a part, or was used for a hardwire phone. If you don't need a phone you can ignore it or put a blanking plate over it. If you need a phone, figure out where the wires go and either hardwire a phone or hook a new jack to them.